# RDBMS schema for unknown columns

Tags: schema, rdbms

I have a project with a MySQL database, and I would like to be able to upload various datasets. Say I am building a restaurant reviews aggregator. So we would like to keep adding all sources of restaurant reviews we could get our hands on, and keeping all the information.

I have a table review_sources

```
=========================
| id | name             |
=========================
| 1  | Zagat            |
| 2  | GoodEats Magazine|
| ...                   |
| 50 | Allergy News     |
=========================
```

Now say I have a table reviews

```
=====================================================================
| id | Restaurant Name      | source_id | Star Rating | Description |
=====================================================================
| 0  | Joey's Burgers       | 1         | 3.5         | Wow!        | 
| 1  | Jamal's Steaks       | 1         | 3.5         | Yummy!      |
| 2  | Jenny's Crepes       | 1         | 4.5         | Sweet!      |
| ....                                                              |
| 253| Jeeva's Curries      | 3         | 4           | Spicy!      |
=====================================================================
```

Now suppose someone wants to add reviews from "Allergy News", they have a field "nut-free". Or a source of reviews could describe the degree of kashrut compliance, or halal compliance or vegan-friendliness. I as a designer don't know the possible optional fields future data sources may have. I want to be able to answer queries:

- What are all the fields in the Zagat reviews?
- For review id=x, what is value of the optional field "vegan-friendly"?

So how do I design a schema that can handle these disparate data sources and answer these queries? My reasons for not going for NoSQL are that I do want certain types of normalization, and that this is part of an existing MySQL based project.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a many-to-many relationship with a table containing a `review_id`, a `field` (e.g. "vegan-friendly") and the value of the field.  Then of course a reviews_fields table to map one to the other.

Cheers